# What is this vector notation?

Tags: vectors

My physics teacher assigned this problem: "Evaluate $\vec\nabla \vec x^2 $ where $\vec x^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$ and $\vec\nabla = \hat{\imath}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat{\jmath}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\hat{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

I know how to compute the problem. But I am confused about this vector $\vec x^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$. I thought vectors have a norm and direction. But it looks like this is only a norm. I am used to vectors always having components, $\hat{\imath},\hat{\jmath},\hat{k}$.

Could anyone shed some light on the subject? What is this notation?

Comment: It's not a vector, it's the square of its norm.

Comment: $\vec x^2$ is a compact notation for $\vec x \cdot\vec x=|\vec x|^2$. $\vec x^2$ is NOT a vector.

Comment: I just hate physics notations...

Comment: The euclidean inner product in space $\Bbb C^n$ is defined as $$(\vec x|\vec y)=\vec x\cdot\vec y=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\bar y_k$$ Then I assume that $$(\vec x|\vec x)=\vec x^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ is the standard norm in $\Bbb R^3$ where the coordinates are $x,y,z$.

Comment: That notation is quite unconventional.  More often, we write $\vec x \cdot \vec x$ or $|\vec x|^2$ or $\vec r\cdot \vec r$ or $|\vec r|^2$ to mean $\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\vec x ^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$ seems to be the square of the [length](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html) of the vector $\vec x$. This is often written as $\|\vec x \|^2$, where $\|\vec x\|$ is the length of the vector $\vec x$.

The symbol $\vec\nabla$ is the [gradient operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient). We can think of $\vec x^2$ as a function where
$$(x,y,z) \longmapsto x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$
The gradient of the function $\vec x^2$ would give
$$\vec \nabla \vec x^2 = 2x{\bf i} \ + \ 2y{\bf j} \ + \ 2z{\bf k} $$

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\vec{x}^2$ is presumably being used to mean $(\vec{x})^2$, which is equivalent to $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}$. It's not a vector, it's just the square of a norm.

Comment: If $\vec x^2$ is undefined then so is $(\vec x)^2$.  There is no difference between the two.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in my answer.